# Interface does not implement error (missing Error method)

Tags: go

I'm writing image converter program with Golang. Here's one of my file.

```
package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/gif"
    "image/jpeg"
    "image/png"
    "io"
)

type Converter interface {
    convimg(io.Writer) error
}

type jpgConverter struct {
    img image.Image
}

type pngConverter struct {
    img image.Image
}

type gifConverter struct {
    img image.Image
}

func convert(c Converter) error {
    return c.convimg  //compile error
}

func (c jpgConverter) convimg(dist io.Writer) error {
    return jpeg.Encode(dist, c.img, nil)
}

func (c pngConverter) convimg(dist io.Writer) error {
    return png.Encode(dist, c.img)
}

func (c gifConverter) convimg(dist io.Writer) error {
    return gif.Encode(dist, c.img, nil)
}
```

I use interface for duck typing so that I can use one same method for any type conversion.
But a compile error occurred in `convert` method, and the error message says `cannot use c.convimg (type func(io.Writer) error) as type error in return argument: func(io.Writer) error does not implement error (missing Error method)`.
I define `error` as return type in the interface, but Where's the wrong point?

Comment: You are not actually *calling* c.convimg, you are returning the method.

Comment: The error is actually pretty clear. You're returning a function of type `func(io.Writer) error`, when you should be returning just an `error`.

Comment: Actually `return c.convimg` does not mean that it returns an `error` as return value. It is actually ruturning a `func(io.Writer) error {...}` definition instead of returning an `error` as return value as the function requires.

Comment: Got it now, very silly mistake. Maybe I'm getting tired today. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments above, `return c.convimg` returns a function. I should write it like:

```
func convert(c Converter, w io.Writer) error
    return c.convimg(w)
```